# Can I Improve how I'm creating this View In MySQL its very Slow?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Database set so data for tasks are posted into the database automatically. Each task is in a section and each section has its own table. There are 20 some tables with all the information in them. I need to get all this information into a Single view so I can display it visually. Currently I am doing the following for each task and there are 118 tasks.

Starting MySQL tables

```
  **Main_table**            
ID   | Dis | Div | inspect
-----|-----|-----|--------
1001 | as  | ad  | Yes
1111 | pq  | ad  | No

CREATE TABLE Main_table(
   ID      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Dis     VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,Div     VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,inspect VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Dis,Div,inspect) VALUES (1001,'as','ad','Yes');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Dis,Div,inspect) VALUES (1111,'pq','ad','No');


 **Sec10_table**    
ID  | task101
----|--------
1001| Null
1111| Good

 CREATE TABLE Sec10_table(
       ID      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
      ,task101 VARCHAR(4) 
    );
    INSERT INTO mytable(ID,task101) VALUES (1001,NULL);
    INSERT INTO mytable(ID,task101) VALUES (1111,'Good');


     **Sec11_table**        
ID   | Task111 | Task112
-----|---------|--------
1001 | Bad     | Good
1111 | Good    | Bad

CREATE TABLE Sec11_table(
   ID      INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Task111 VARCHAR(4) 
  ,Task112 VARCHAR(4) 
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Task111,Task112) VALUES (1001,'Bad','Good');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,Task111,Task112) VALUES (1111,'Good','Bad');
```

What I'm doing now

```
   Create View Master_view As

Select Main_table.ID AS ID,
'Task 101' AS Task,
Sec10_table.Task101 AS Results,
Main_table.Dis AS Dis,
Main_table.Div AS Div,
Main_table.inspect AS Inspect,
10 AS Section
From (Main_table
LEFT JOIN Sec10_table ON (Main_table.ID = Sec10_table.ID))
Where Sec10_table.Task101 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

Select Main_table.ID AS ID,
'Task 111' AS Task,
Sec11_table.Task111 AS Results,
Main_table.Dis AS Dis,
Main_table.Div AS Div,
Main_table.inspect AS Inspect,
11 AS Section
From (Main_table
LEFT JOIN Sec11_table ON (Main_table.ID = Sec11_table.ID))
WHERE Sec11_table.Task111 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

Select Main_table.ID AS ID,
'Task 112' AS Task,
Sec11_table.Task112 AS Results,
Main_table.Dis AS Dis,
Main_table.Div AS Div,
Main_table.inspect AS Inspect,
11 AS Section
From (Main_table
LEFT JOIN Sec11_table ON (Main_table.ID = Sec11_table.ID))
WHERE Sec11_table.Task112 IS NOT NULL
```

Creates this view.

```
                  **Master_View**
ID   | Task     | Results | Dis  | Div  | Inspect | Section
-----|----------|---------|------|------|---------|--------
1001 | Task 111 | Bad     | as   | ad   | Yes     | 11
1001 | Task 112 | Good    | as   | ad   | Yes     | 11
1111 | Task 101 | Good    | pq   | ad   | No      | 10
1111 | Task 111 | Good    | pq   | ad   | No      | 11
1111 | Task 112 | Bad     | pq   | ad   | No      | 11
```

I have been trying to find different way of doing this that might make it simpler and more efficient because currently it is running too slow.

Comment: Try explain a bit your expected . result .. because the query seems not really useful for your goal ..

Comment: Can you change the database schema to have _one_ table for all the sections, storing the section numbers in a new column in that table instead of as table names?

Comment: @TerjeD. Unfortunately someone else set up how the data is coming in So I would have to get them to change it in order to change the schema.  I was hoping to avoid that but maybe that is what I have to do.

Comment: Why are you using a view?

Comment: @Strawberry We are using the view to update a table every night with the new data that has come in.    We are inserting all data that has come in since the last time the insert statement has run. This is probably not the best way to do this either.